Second partial derivatives as tangent vectors on a smooth manifold
Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold along with a chart $(U,x)$. I'm wondering if second partial derivatives can also be seen as tangent vectors. I'm assuming this is not the case, since for example one can easily see that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^1x^2}(f\cdot g)\neq f\cdot\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^1 x^2}+g\cdot\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^1x^2}$$The reason I was suspecting this is that I wanted to simplify$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}\right\rangle-\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}\left\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right\rangle$$and thought about just using the normal product rule of a bilinear form to pull the derivatives inside. So really my 2 questions are: am I wrong about the second partial derivatives not being tangent vectors? And how could I simplify the above expression?

I assume you are familiar with the identification of vector fields on $M$ with derivations on the space of functions $M \rightarrow \mathbb R$, calling the basis vectors in a chart $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.
As you noticed correctly, second derivative operators aren't derivations, so can't be interpreted as vector fields.
One way to see why would be to look at the components of such a "vector field" in different coordinate systems / charts to see that there is no "good" transformation rule that only depends on the first derivatives of the chart transitions.
However, the commutator of two vector fields (which is called their Lie Bracket) is again a derivation, as the commutator of derivations always is.
What you are looking at here, is something different, however.
It relates to the way we can actually take derivatives of vector fields $Y$ on Riemannian manifolds, namely by the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$, whose Christoffel symbols look similar to your expression. The Christoffel symbols are the components in
$$(\nabla_X Y)^i = \partial_X Y^i + X^k\Gamma^i_{kl} Y^l$$
This is treated in any course in Riemannian geometry (and is important for General Relativity etc.).
For example
$$ \partial_i \left< X,Y\right> = \left< \nabla_iX,Y\right> + \left< X,\nabla_iY\right>  $$

There is indeed a sense of taking "derivatives of derivatives" in differentiable manifolds (I'm avoiding saying "second derivatives" because the resulting object is somewhat different). And indeed, they are not tangent vectors, because they do not obey the Leibniz rule. They are a different kind of differential operator.
Let's look at your expression. You want to simplify $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \left\langle \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^l}\right\rangle$. Let's consider this inner product as a Riemannian metric $g = g_{ij} dx^i dx^j$ (using the Einstein summation convention with $g_{ij} : U \to \mathbb R$ smooth functions). On one level, all we're doing is differentiating $g_{jl} = g(\partial_{x^j}, \partial_{x^l})$. On another more interesting level (one independent of coordinates), we're differentiating $g$ itself. There are two ways of doing this: using a Lie derivative, or using a Levi-Civita connection. These both take a bit of explanation, but very basically, the Lie derivative $\mathfrak L_{\partial_{x^i}}$ is measuring how $g$ changes with respect to the coordinate vector field $\partial_{x^i}$, while the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla_{\partial_{x^i}}$ measures how $g$ changes in the immediate direction of $\partial_{x^i}$, and then how it continues to change in the geometry of the space.
It so happens that when the Lie derivative or Levi-Civita connection with respect to a vector field $X$ is applied to a smooth function $f$, then the result is:
$$
\mathfrak L_X f = Xf \quad \textrm{and} \quad \nabla_X f = Xf,
$$
exactly as we'd expect. However, when $f = \langle Y, Z \rangle$ is the inner product of smooth vector fields, the Levi-Civita connection indeed obeys the product rule; the Lie derivative does not:
$$
\nabla_X \langle Y,Z \rangle = \langle \nabla_X Y, Z \rangle + \langle Y, \nabla_X Z\rangle
$$
$$
\mathfrak L_X \langle Y, Z \rangle \neq \langle \mathfrak L_X Y, Z \rangle + \langle Y, \mathfrak L_X Z \rangle
$$
So I think you want to look into coordinate expressions for Levi-Civita connections.
